# Удаление с ArrayList

Tags: java

Почему не удаляет элемент, который меньше переменной qVal из ArrayList?

```
 int hVal = (int)aAver;
 Integer qVal = new Integer(hVal);
 for(int i =0; i<arrData.size();i++){
     if(arrData.get(i)<qVal){
        arrData.remove(arrData.get(i));
     };
     System.out.println("List-> " + arrData.get(i));
 }
```

Comment: А Вы попробуйте вот так `arrData.remove(i);`.

Comment: все равно не получается

Answer (score 5):

Метод [remove](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int)) для `ArrayList` выглядит так:

```
public E remove(int index)
```

где index - индекс элемента, который должен быть удален.

Соответственно, вместо того, чтоб писать

```
arrData.remove(arrData.get(i));
```

надо писать удаление по индексу

```
arrData.remove(i);
```

---

Хотя раз работа идет с `Integer`, то и `arrData.remove(arrData.get(i));` должен работать но надо знать и помнить: **удалять из коллекции в цикле нельзя, надо проходить коллекцию итератором**, к примеру:

```
List<String> names = ....
Iterator<String> i = names.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
   String s = i.next(); 
   if (// условие ) {
       i.remove();
   }
}
```

Ну либо бежать по коллекции с конца к началу.

---

В итоге с итератором будет как-то так:

```
Iterator<Integer> i = arrData.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
   Integer num = i.next(); 
   if(num < qVal){
      i.remove();

       System.out.println("List-> " + num);
   }
}

System.out.println(arrData);
```

Comment: работает, но не удаляет элементы которые меньше переменной qVal, a когда меняю знак на > , то удаляет элементы которые больше

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, А разве у автора вот [это](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) не сработает? Другое дело, что он удаляет только первое вхождение.

Comment: @ЕгорМяус приведите пример со значениями в вашей коллекции arrData и что вводите в hVal... посмотрим.... вообще для удаления в цикле надо использовать итератор

Comment: Значения в arrData вводятся с клавиатуры, а hVal это среднее этих значений. Посчитать среднее арифмитическое
элементов массива и вывести все числа в порядке их ввода, которые не меньше среднего арифметического.

Comment: @ЕгорМяус но ведь какие-то исходные данные на которых тестируете у вас же есть..... но как бы то ни было... вам нужно бегать по коллекции итератором, описал в ответе об этом

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!

Comment: Получилось))))))