# Работа с интерфейсом Map

Tags: java

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста, никак не могу справиться с задачкой. Есть HashMap  с данными, .
По ней делаю перебор.
Удаляю из нее элемент и естественно, у меня key с данным номером удален, и когда идет перебор далее, у меня NullPointer. Как можно удалить элемент, но так, чтобы key сместился? Я уже и копировал в другую и что только не делал, никак.
Может у кого-то есть способ? или знаете как безболезненно удалять, я и через Iterator делал, все равно нет в итоге при повторном переборе этого key.

Последняя мысля была такая

```
HashMap<Integer, Wagon> copy = new HashMap<Integer, Wagon>(tempMapOfWagons);
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Wagon> pair: copy.entrySet()){
       if (pair.getKey().equals(getKeyNumber))
       System.out.println(getKeyNumber);
       tempMapOfWagons.remove(getKeyNumber);
 }
```

А так получаю ConcurrentEx

```
tempMapOfWagons.remove(getKeyNumber);
int i = 0;
for (HashMap.Entry<Integer, String> m : tempMapOfWagons.entrySet()) {
      mapNewOfWagons.put(i, m.getValue());
      i++;
}
```

При работе с итератором делал так, переписывал в новую мапу, смещая элементы

```
int i = 0;
for (Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Wagon>> iterator = tempMapOfWagons.entrySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
     Map.Entry<Integer, Wagon> e = iterator.next();
     if (e.getKey().equals(getKeyNumber)) {
            iterator.remove();
            iterator.next();
     } else {
            mapNewOfWagons.put(i, e.getValue());
            i++;
     }
 }
```

Comment: покажи пример как с итератором работал

Comment: добавил варианты свои, как делал, во всех случаях получал либо Concurrent либо Null.

Comment: при работе с итератором вы теряете один iterator.next(); А перед этой командой лучше проверять есть ли след эл  iterator.hasNext(); Добавьте в вопрос описание, когда и как получаете NPE (исключение крайне не информативное, а вы предлагаете гадать где оно вылезло)

Comment: у тебя аж два `.next()` - логично что ошибка....должен быть один `hasNext` и один `next`

Comment: Я бы, чтоб не путаться что где - делал бы через while https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/578619/191482  ....... либо, если хочется делать через `for`  то по коллекции бегут с конца

Comment: но я с итератором так делал, в итоге потом когда я в цикле опять элу коллекцию проверяю, у меня Null, так как например, у меня 25 key нет уже, так как его удалил. Мне надо так, чтобы на метро 25 встал элемент 26, но key остался у него 25.

Comment: ммм.. проще было задачу озвучить)) А таких удалений в итоге будет несколько или одно? А то может проще всё удалить ненужное, а потом ключи пересчитать

Comment: Будут удаляться последовательно, если совпадет условие, в итоге удалится все, сразу нельзя удалять, иначе было бы просто) тут именно тупик в этом, что key не пересчитывается

Comment: если у вас карта "номер по порядку" -> "вагон", то вам нужен просто список, и ничего перенумеровывать не придется.

Comment: Уточнение, у меня в одном условие идет replace, то key, в другом, если первое не попало идет удаление. Если список использовать, то как мне заменить старые данные на новые. И мне кажется я туплю) Я в списке могу по номеру вагона найти запись и заменить ее, так как номера уникальны, две записи с одинаковыми номерами вагонов не может быть

Comment: @Владислав как уже сказали, будет проще если вы опишите задачу, а то помогающие пробираются в слепую.

Comment: Но я же описал, удалить элемент из коллекции, но так , чтобы ключ пересчитался, то есть, чтобы после удаления 2го элемента, получить не [0=qqq, 1=ddd, 3=fff], а получить [0=qqq, 1=ddd, 2=fff], то есть 3й элемент, стал вторым после удаления

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот вам пример удаления значения из Map

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
Map <Integer, String> pair = new HashMap<>();
pair.put(1, "one");
pair.put(2, "two");
pair.put(3, "three");
pair.put(4, "four");
pair.put(5, "five");

Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> iterator = pair.entrySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()){
    Map.Entry<Integer, String> nextElement = iterator.next();
    Integer key = nextElement.getKey();
    String value = nextElement.getValue();

    if (key==3) iterator.remove();
}

pair.forEach((k,v)->{System.out.println(k+" * " + v);});
```

Comment: Но в итоге, опять у меня элементы не подряд. Получилось вот что, после удаления 25 элемента 24 * 52426525, ОДС, Канатово
26 * 52425659, КРЫМ, Севастополь-Товарный. Но моя цель, чтобы  52425659, КРЫМ, Севастополь-Товарный был 25м элементом после удаления

Comment: Что значит не подряд? Map - пара, т.е. ключ и значение. Если В данном примере мы удалили один элемент при переборе, то их осталось 4, а ключи 3 и значение  three удалились. Под тройку ужи никто не подставится, это же пара

Comment: это я понимаю, ну вот и вопрос в этом, как можно сделать так, чтобы под 3ку подставилось 4ка этой же коллекции. Перебором этой же коллекции не получается

Comment: если вам нужен именно Map, то придется танцевать с бубном. Во-первых, если вы хотите подставить последующий элемент коллекции на место предыдущего, то вы должны понимать , что HashMap вообще не гарантирует порядок элементов. Тогда используйте либо TreeMap , либо LinkedHashMap. первый автоматом сортирует по ключу, второй - сохраняет тот порядок, который был при добавлении. Это зависит от того, что в вашем понимании следующий элемент, который должен быть подставлен под предыдущий

Comment: Это-то я все понимаю, но выше подсказали, что лучше список использовать, удобнее будет. Так сказать коллективный разум помогает) Почему за день танцев с бубном над Map, не додумался, что проще List использовать) Но спасибо за помощь все равно)

Comment: я как бы начинал с чего - если вам нужен именно Map)) конечно ArrayList проще, там индексы как в обычном массиве

Comment: Да дело в том, что изначально мне нужна была MAp, тосле я переделал все в объекты, это по Вашему же и комментарию моего вопроса про сортировку Map, но немного столкнулся с трудностями, так как у меня весь алгоритм был на Map построен, вот теперь какие-то мапы остались, и от них избавляюсь, сейчас переделаю в список.

Comment: Вы понимаете, что очень сложно оценить архитектуру приложения, исходя из куска кода в 20 строк. Сделать заключения по поводу рациональности использования какой-либо конкретной коллекции заочно... Ну это скорее к экстрасенсам, а не к программистам) ) )

Comment: Согласен, я стараюсь задавать вопросы конкретно, с минимальным кодом, но в итоге приходится все равно зарываться глубже(( Так же как и с удалением, хотел поминимуму задать вопрос, а не вышло все равно